# While "Printf" in swift getting "optional" text before actual text

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to print value on my table view row everything goes correct but value is printing like

```
println("\(cell?.textLabel?.text)")
```

**Optional("Some text")** instead of **"Some text"**

Is there any way in swift to print actual value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is printing an optional values so you need to unwrap it like:

```
if let yourCell = cell?.textLabel?.text {
        println(yourCell)
}
```

Refer this [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) to know more about optionals.

Answer (score 0):

print like this

```
println(cell.textLabel?.text)
```